# Batch HTTP requests in Play!Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have the current set of of routes implemented (for example):

```
GET     /api/:version/:entity               my.controllers.~~~~~
GET     /api/:version/:entity/:id           my.controllers.~~~~~
POST    /api/:version/:entity               my.controllers.~~~~~
POST    /api/:version/:entity/:id           my.controllers.~~~~~
DELETE  /api/:version/:entity               my.controllers.~~~~~

POST    /api/:version/search/:entity        my.controllers.~~~~~
```

And they work beautifully. Now let's say I want to implement a "batch endpoint" for the same API. It should look something like this:

```
POST    /api/:version/batch                 my.controllers.~~~~~
```

and the body should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "call": "/api/1/customer",
        "body": {
            "name": "antonio",
            "email": "tonysmallhands@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "call": "/api/1/customer/2",
        "body": {
            "name": "mario"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "call": "/api/1/company"
    },
    {
        "method": "DELETE",
        "call": "/api/1/company/22"
    }
]
```

To do that I would like to know how I can call the play framework router to pass those requests? I was planning  to use something similar as what is advised for unit tests:

```
@Test
public void badRoute() {
  Result result = play.test.Helpers.routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/xx/Kiki"));
  assertThat(result).isNull();
}
```

by going into the source code of `routeAndCall()`, you find something like this:

```
 /**
 * Use the Router to determine the Action to call for this request and executes it.
 * @deprecated
 * @see #route instead
 */
@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
public static Result routeAndCall(FakeRequest fakeRequest) {
    try {
        return routeAndCall((Class<? extends play.core.Router.Routes>)FakeRequest.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("Routes"), fakeRequest);
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}

/**
 * Use the Router to determine the Action to call for this request and executes it.
 * @deprecated
 * @see #route instead
 */
public static Result routeAndCall(Class<? extends play.core.Router.Routes> router, FakeRequest fakeRequest) {
    try {
        play.core.Router.Routes routes = (play.core.Router.Routes)router.getClassLoader().loadClass(router.getName() + "$").getDeclaredField("MODULE$").get(null);
        if(routes.routes().isDefinedAt(fakeRequest.getWrappedRequest())) {
            return invokeHandler(routes.routes().apply(fakeRequest.getWrappedRequest()), fakeRequest);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is there a less "hacky" way to do this with Play (I am not against mixing Scala and Java to get to it) than to copy the above code? I would have also like to give the option of executing the batched calls in parallel or in sequence ... I guess instantiating only one `Routes` using the class loader would be problematic then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method call to route your fake requests:
`Play.current.global.onRouteRequest`. Please see this post for a full example: http://yefremov.net/blog/play-batch-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [WS API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaWS) for that, but personally I'd just create a private methods for collecting data and use them from both - 'single' and also 'batch' actions - it will be faster for sure.

Comment: I did consider this (in desperation). I would like to avoid to have to send extra HTTP requests to my server ... because after all one big advantage a batch endpoint is to execute a lot of calls with the over head of only one HTTP request.

Comment: Therefore just go with second suggested approach, in your `batch` action you can first collect ie. list of id's to fetch and then perform single query and build return object

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have no problems with te general principles of batching ... the only problem I have is that I do not know how to call play frameworks routing from inside my code.